# SQL Query for timestamp

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sql

I had following Table

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
    ( `Name` varchar(7), `Address` varchar(55), `City` varchar(15),`Contact` int,`timestamp` int)
;

INSERT INTO Customer
    (`Name`,`Address`, `City`, `Contact`,`timestamp`)
VALUES
    ('Jack','New City','LA',79878458,456125),
    ('Joseph','New Lane23','LA',87458458,794865),
   ('Rosy','Old City','Paris',79878458,215125),
   ('Maria','New City','LA',79878458,699125),
   ('Jack','New City','LA',79878458,456125),
   ('Rosy','Old City','Paris',79878458,845125),
   ('Jack','New Main Street','New York',79878458,555525),
   ('Joseph','Near Bank','SAn Francisco',79878458,984521)

;
```

I want to get all customer record with highest timestamp without duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get all customer record with highest timestamp without
>   duplication.

Use `DISTINCT` operator and `ORDER BY` clause like

```
select distinct `Name`,`Address`, `City`, `Contact`,`timestamp`
from customer
order by `timestamp` desc;
```

In that case you can use `JOIN` query like

```
select t1.*
from customer t1 join
(select Name, max(`timestamp`) as maxstamp
 from customer
 group by Name) xx 
 on t1.Name = xx.Name
 and t1.`timestamp` = xx.maxstamp;
```

Comment: But want to show record with same name having highest timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
select name,max(timestamp),Address,City,Contact from Customer group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` 
group by name,Address,City,Contact,timestamp
order by timestamp desc
```

Comment: But want to show record with same name having highest timestamp

Comment: if your databse is mysql you should try this: "SELECT Name,max(timestamp) as timestamp FROM `customer` 
group by Name
order by Name asc,timestamp asc"

Answer (score 0):

I'm joining the Customer table with itself, the condition `c1.timestamp<c2.timestamp` on the join clause combined with `c2.timestamp IS NULL`
will make sure that only the latest record for each person is returned. I put `DISTINCT` because on your sample data there are two records for Jack with the same timestamp:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  c1.*
FROM
  Customer c1 LEFT JOIN Customer c2
  ON c1.Name=c2.Name
     AND c1.Contact=c2.Contact -- you might want to remove this
     AND c1.timestamp<c2.timestamp
WHERE
  c2.timestamp IS NULL
ORDER BY
  Name, Address
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a44fb/2).

Comment: select t1.*
from customer t1 join
(select Name, max(`timestamp`) as maxstamp
 from customer
 group by Name) xx 
 on t1.Name = xx.Name
 and t1.`timestamp` = xx.maxstamp;

Comment: But if any rows is repeated/duplicate it also show that row repeatedly

Comment: @LalitJadiya using a subquery is an alternative solution, but I prefer using a LEFT JOIN ... yes, if you have two contacts with different details but same max timestamp they will be duplicated... but which record do you want to return in that case?